# Arduino Blink Testing With C#

Tags: c#, arduino

I have been able to get a "reaction" light from my Ardunio Uno from C# with the following code:

```
using System.IO.Ports;

private void OnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SerialPort serial = new SerialPort("COM7", 9600)
   serial.Open();
   serial.WriteLine("A");
   serial.Close();
}
```

I have also setup an "Off" button with the same, but with the WriteLine("a").

I have the following code uploaded to an Ardunio Uno with the default Windows Ardunio software:

```
int message = 0;
int LEDPin = 13;
int LED = 0;

void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
 if (Serial.available() > 0)
 {
  message = Serial.read();
  if (message == 'A')
  {
   LED = 255;
   Serial.println("LED on");
  }
  if (message == 'a')
  {
   LED = 0;
   Serial.println("LED off");
  }
 }
}
```

Now that I have the Adrunio code put into the Uno device, I am expecting that this should turn the onboard pin 13 LED on and off, but nothing happens.

On the Uno board, there is a small light that flashes next to "TX" and "RX" when the button click happens (so I know something is being sent to the board...). But nothing happens to the onboard LED.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a variable called `LED` doesn't affect the LED at all.  You need to configure the pin as output:

```
pinMode(LEDPin, HIGH);
```

write to the pin to turn it on:

```
digitalWrite(LEDPin, HIGH);
```

and off:

```
digitalWrite(LEDPin, LOW);
```

Here's a working LED flashing [program](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial-0007/BlinkingLED)

Comment: I'm a bit confused about setting the pinMode setting in the Ardunio code. Could you please write out what it should be for me please?

Comment: I wrote out the three lines you need and what they do.  If you replace the lines in your code with them, it should work.  You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of how Arduino code works, though, so I would suggest you find some basic tutorials to get up to speed.

Answer (score 0):

Equating LED to a certain number just doesn't work. First you need to configure a PIN to OUTPUT or INPUT using this function. You basically put this line of code under setup().

```
pinMode(LED, HIGH);
```

or

```
pinMode(LED, LOW);
```

Then you can make it light up or not by using this function. This one's usually under loop().

```
digitalWrite(LEDPin, HIGH);
```

or

```
digitalWrite(LEDPin, LOW);
```

Your LED variable is useless here unless you have something in mind to use this for that's not stated.

```
int message = 0;
int LEDPin = 13;
int LED = 0;

void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(LEDPin, OUTPUT);     
}

void loop()
{
 if (Serial.available() > 0)
 {
  message = Serial.read();
  if (message == 'A')
   {
   LED = 255;
   digitalWrite(LEDPin, HIGH);
   Serial.println("LED on");
  }
  if (message == 'a')
  {
   LED = 0;
   digitalWrite(LEDPin, LOW);
   Serial.println("LED off");
  }
 }
}
```